# Can you recast variables of typedef into another type in C header file?

Tags: c

I'm learning embedded C and while going through some files a have found a line which I am struggling to understand:

```
void (* TxCpltCallback)(struct __SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi);
```

Is it some kind of recasting? That line comes from  file `stm32l4xx_hal_spi.h` which is high level library for STM32 microcontrollers.

Comment: It is a *function pointer*. You can research the term.

Comment: ...to a "callback" function -- which is a function meant to be provided as a parameter to another function that changes how the function behaves in some way. For many embedded systems, the headers are quite specialized and include a number of things you would not normally write in a header as you are learning C. Good to look at it all, just don't get frustrated if what you find in a system header looks a lot different than what you see in your C textbook.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have to learn about function pointers too :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a function pointer.  The following is a brief example:

```
void (* TxCpltCallback)(struct __SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi);

void foo(struct __SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
{
}

void bar(TxCpltCallback cb)
{
    struct __SPI_HandleTypeDef spi;
    cb(&spi); // Calls foo
}

int main(void)
{
    bar(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It isn't a `typedef` as I expect, but global data?